# Tengo un pequeño error en vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Actualmente cuando tengo 2 arreglos iguales en vuejs con las mismas llaves y a actualizo 1 se actualiza el otro tambien, no entiendo por que pasa esto

Ejemplo:

```
    // state having some demo data
const state = {
    stockActual:[],
    stockSave:[],
    stockNum:0
};
const mutations = {
    addstockActual(state,payload){
      state.stockActual.push(payload)
      state.stockSave.push(payload)
    },
    addstocks(state,payload){
      let stock_item = state.stockActual.find(item => item.id === payload.id) // con filter hacemos de este modo buscamos el id donde sea diferente al payload o al id que le pasamos y asi borra el elemento
      if (payload.stock !== '' && payload.stock > 0) {
        stock_item.stock = Number(stock_item.stock) + payload.stock
        console.log('actualizado')
      }else{
        let stock_item_save = state.stockSave.find(item => item.id === payload.id) // con filter hacemos de este modo buscamos el id donde sea diferente al payload o al id que le pasamos y asi borra el elemento
        stock_item.stock = stock_item_save.stock;

        console.log(stock_item_save.stock);
      }
    }
};
const getters = {
    numstock: (state) => state.stockActual
};
const actions = {
    setStocks({commit},stock){
      commit('addstockActual',stock)
    },
    setStockVehiculo({commit},stock){
      commit('addstocks',stock)
    }
};

export default{
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

Esto lo hago en vuex en unos de mis módulos de vuex , cuando hago esto  stockActual lo busco y luego lo actualizo pero también actualiza en el stockSave, son arreglos totalmente diferentes por se actualizan los dos? , cabe destacar que desde la vista solo llamo al getter numstock no envió mas nada y el stockSave solo le agrego datos desde aquí :(, esto me paso también en una vista de vuejs, que estoy haciendo mal ? Soy novato en vuejs , de antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Será porque en `addstockActual` agregas el mismo elemento a ambos arreglos?

Comment: Aunque agregue el mismo elemento, no serian variables separadas? O en este caso al ser el mismo elemento y estar en variables separadas se modificara en las dos variables cada ves ?

Comment: No, porque básicamente estas guardando una dirección de memoria. Si un objeto esta en dos arreglos al mismo tiempo, ambos arreglos apuntan a la misma dirección de memoria, y por lo tanto al acceder a él desde uno de los arreglos, estás modificando los valores de dicha dirección. Por lo tanto cambia para todos. La solución es que hagas una copia de ese objeto para cada arreglo. https://www.javascripttutorial.net/object/3-ways-to-copy-objects-in-javascript/

Comment: A ok, entonces ahora entiendo mucho mejor, muchas gracias.!